# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS White screen after boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, white-screen

I am having trouble installing ubuntu onto my computer. When I boot my computer, it takes me to a completely white screen(as shown below). I am entirely new to this and would like some guidance in resolving this issue. Thank you in advance for all your help.

Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 5600G with Radeon Graphics
Graphics Card: GTX 1650
Ram: 16 GB
Motherboard:  ROG STRIX B550-A GAMING

[image]

Comment: Are you booting Ubuntu with an USB drive?

Comment: Yes I am booting from a USB drive

Comment: Did you verify your ISO after download & before writing to USB-media as per documentation?  (ie. https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0), though I find the write of the ISO to media is more likely an issue. Given you can't verify the write using that box (*as you can't read anything on the screen*), I'd boot the USB-media on another box & verify the write of ISO using another box.  You didn't mention which Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS product you're asking about, Desktop? Server? etc.  (*I've assumed Desktop*)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue , seems a problem on kernel 5.19 and AMD cpu .

I resolved changing grub configuration, adding `nomodeset` to grub, like this:

edit grub config using gedit or nano :

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

change this line:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

to this:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`

save and update with `sudo update-grub2`

This prevents Linux loading a specific driver. It's a workaround not a solution but at least you can use yor pc. Anyway kernel 6 should fix it.